# Locate the indexes of rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have stored in a struct file in matlab a database and the correspondant label files. In order to read my database matrix from the struct into a matrix I am using the following matlab command:

```
train_data_matrix = (cat(1, train_data.f2));
```

The size of the train_data struct is 883. However since there are some empty samples in the end the size of the `train_data_matrix` is `833`. My problem is that I have annotation for all the samples. Thereby the size of the annotation is `883x1` How can I remove from the annotation vector the rows that are empty in the database matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isempty` to check for missing values and remove them

```
% Store data in a cell array (preserves missing values)
tmp = {train_data.f2};

% Create a logical array that is TRUE where the missing values are
toremove = cellfun(@isempty, tmp);

% Convert to an array (removes missing values as you've mentioned)
data = cat(1, tmp{:});

% Create an array of annotations (after removing the ones that are missing data)
annotations = cat(1, train_data(~toremove).annotations);
```

Comment: The variable train_data.f2 is not a struct thought. Can I dot the index to remove without using cellfun?

Comment: @JoseRamon `tmp` is a cell array though (each element contains the `f2` value for each `struct`) which is why I use `cellun`. Are you getting an error?